# Plotting a partition of a bipartite graph takes much more time than the entire graph

Tags: r, plot, igraph, graph-theory

In my code, plotting the entire bipartite graph takes much less time than plotting one of the projections alone (which, of course, have less nodes than the bipartite graph, since it is only a part of the bipartite graph). How can it be?

Here is the code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(igraph)
library(tictoc)
nodes <- read.csv("./ma_nodes.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
links <- read.csv("./ma_edges.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
nodes$type <- as.logical(nodes$IsInvestor)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
net.bp <- bipartite_projection(net, multiplicity=F)
net.prj1 = net.bp$proj1
net.prj2 = net.bp$proj2

tic("Plotting bibpartite net")
plot(net)
toc()

tic("Plotting prj2")
plot(net.prj2)
toc()

tic("Plotting prj1")
plot(net.prj1)
toc()
```

Here is the result:

```
Plotting bibpartite net: 5.04 sec elapsed
Plotting prj2: 0.21 sec elapsed
Plotting prj1: 77.9 sec elapsed
```

Also note that using Sys.time() to measure time (and taking the difference end time - start time), this effect is not captured. But this is not true: plotting the last graph takes way more time than plotting the other twos. It is a problem of sys.time() which is not able to capture that (but probably that's for another question)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be better as a comment. But I don't have the necessary reputation. Thus, I will answer your question more detailed.

You did not provide a sample. So I can only make an assumption. Most likely your projection has a lot more edges compared to the bipartite network. Depending on your specific network this can extensively increase the time to create the plot.

A bipartite projection from an undirected network with 500 edges would result in 124750 (or n*(n-1)/2) edges.

```
library(igraph)
library(tictoc)

g <- data.frame(c(1:500), "A")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(g)
V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type
bp <- bipartite_projection(g)

gsize(g)
500

gsize(bp$proj1)
124750
```

And plotting time would increase by 8.5 sec (MacBook Pro from 2015 with Intel i7 & 16 GB RAM):

```
tic("Plotting bibpartite net")
plot(g)
toc()
Plotting bibpartite net: 1.194 sec elapsed

tic("Plotting projected net")
plot(bp$proj1)
toc()
Plotting projected net: 9.621 sec elapsed
```

The problem is that the number of ties in the projected network grows exponentially and so does the time to create the plot.

Comment: yes I aksed the developers of igraph and that was the reason